# Two file upload control in same form takes same name at the time of uploading in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

I have a two file upload control in my form one is for uploading a css file and other is for html file.
my css file name is style.css and html file name is test.html.

Both files are uploaded successfully but both takes a same name when it is uploaded. css file name is at the time of uploading is style.css and html is file name is also style.css.

css file uploading code is :

```
       if(isset($_FILES['css_file']) AND $_FILES['css_file']['name'] != '') {
                        $xyz['upload_path'] = 'theme/'.$folder_name;    
                        $xyz['allowed_types'] = 'css';
                        $xyz['overwrite'] = FALSE;
                        $xyz['file_name'] = $_FILES['css_file']['name'];

                        $this->load->library('upload', $xyz);

                        if (!$this->upload->do_upload('css_file')) {
                            echo $this->upload->display_errors();
                        }else{
                            $abc_array['file'] = $this->upload->data();

                            $array_rc['css_file'] = $abc_array['file']['file_name'];

                         }
        }
```

html file uploading code is :

```
    if(isset($_FILES['html_file']) AND $_FILES['html_file']['name'] != '') {
                        $abc['upload_path'] = 'theme/'.$folder_name;
                        $abc['allowed_types'] = 'html';
                        $abc['overwrite'] = FALSE;
                        $abc['file_name'] = $_FILES['html_file']['name'];

                        $this->load->library('upload', $abc);

                        if (!$this->upload->do_upload('html_file')) {
                            echo $this->upload->display_errors();
                        }else{

                            $xyz_array['file'] = $this->upload->data();

                            $array_rc['html_file'] = $xyz_array['file']['file_name'];

                        }
        }
```

So how can i rename html file at the time of uploading ?

Comment: what i guess is that while uploading you are using same script for css and html file, and before calling to move_uploaded_file you are renaming these file to a hard-coded string.

Comment: i am using a two different script for uploading a css and html file.

Comment: Show your upload code...  from controller

Comment: if you can show your code, then we may be able to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this helps you

```
$this->load->library("upload");
if(isset($_FILES['css_file']) AND $_FILES['css_file']['name'] != '') 
{
    $xyz['upload_path']     = 'theme/'.$folder_name;    
    $xyz['allowed_types']   = 'css';
    $xyz['overwrite']       = FALSE;
    $xyz['file_name']       = $_FILES['css_file']['name'];
    $this->upload->initialize($xyz);
    if (!$this->upload->do_upload('css_file')) 
    {
        echo $this->upload->display_errors();
    }
    else
    {
        print_r($this->upload->data());
    }
}

if(isset($_FILES['html_file']) AND $_FILES['html_file']['name'] != '') 
{
    $abc['upload_path']     = 'theme/'.$folder_name;
    $abc['allowed_types']   = 'html';
    $abc['overwrite']       = FALSE;
    $abc['file_name']       = $_FILES['html_file']['name'];
    $this->upload->initialize($abc);
    if (!$this->upload->do_upload('html_file')) 
    {
        echo $this->upload->display_errors();
    }
    else
    {
        print_r($this->upload->data());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Native

```
$config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;
```

OR

```
$name = $_FILES["userfiles"]['name'];
$config['file_name'] = $name;
```

Comment: it takes a encrypted name but still extension is same.